# Need to solve for t but can not work out how to get t on one side

Tags: physics, problem-solving

I have a object in free fall with $g$ = acceleration, $y$ is the position above the ground and $t$ = time.

I worked out that to find the speed at and $t$ is $dy = g . t$

So to get the position $py$ at time t is $py = y + \cfrac{g}{2}  t^2$

Then to get the time $t$ it would take to reach a distance $d$ is $t = \sqrt { \cfrac{d}{\cfrac{g}{2}}}$

Now I have a starting speed $s$ so to get position $py$ at $t$ is $py = y + \cfrac{g}{2}t^2 + s.t$

The problem I have is I can not work out how to get $t$ on one side of the equation $py = y + \cfrac{g}{2}t^2 + s.t$ where I have position $py$, starting position $y$, acceleration $g$, and starting speed s

I must be missing something basic or just a brain fry, so hope someone can show me how to get the t out to one side. Thanks.

Comment: It's just a quadratic equation in $t$. Do you know how to solve those?

Comment: No I don't remember how but thanks for the tip I have something to search now. From memory it has two solutions called the roots?

Comment: That's right, and I have the formula in my answer if you need a refresher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a quadratic in $t$, so you have two options; you can use the quadratic formula or you can complete the square. The quadratic formula is a little more straightforward, though, and it says that for an equation of the form
$0=c+bt+at^2,$ $$t=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$ Applying this to your equation gives

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
0&=&(y-py)+st+\frac{g}{2}t^2\\
t&=&\frac{-s\pm\sqrt{s^2-4(y-py)\left(\frac{g}{2}\right)}}{2(y-py)}\\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

One quick note: The conventions are that gravity acts in the negative direction of the y-axis, so your quadratic term should be $-\frac{g}{2}t^2.$

Comment: Thank you very much. Totally forgot this stuff so many years since school. I am going in the positive direction as my coordinates are positive in the down direction.